# Mac screen sharing keyboard shortcuts for switching screen do not work (CMD+OPTION+1,2)

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts, vnc, screen-sharing

I'm using a Mac Studio with two attached displays and an iMac which I use the access the Mac Studio via screen sharing. In order two switch in between both VNC streams of the displays of the Mac Studio I usually use the default keyboard shortcut of the screen sharing app on the iMac as follows:

- CMD + OPT + X -> to switch to observation mode
- CMD + OPT + 1/2 -> to switch to the other display
- CMD + OPT + X -> to return to control mode

But for some reason, this stopped working and to be honest, wasn't working reliably to begin with.

Did anybody experience the same issue and has a working solution?